# How a thread is scheduled for "await DoSthAsync"

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-core

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Read(File.OpenText("test.txt")); // content: "read from file"
    Read(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(
      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("read from string")));
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", 
      Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "main thread");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
  static async Task Read(StreamReader sr)
  {
    var s = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", 
      Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, s);
  }
}
```

Output:

> 3: read from file
>
> 1: read from string
>
> 1: main thread

Above, why does `read from file` spawn a new thread but not `read from string` ?

More specifically, why does the asynchronous file IO require a new thread to complete ?

Is it just the wrapped version of the underlying synchronous file IO, which is then dispatched by spawning a new thread ?

Comment: I'd guess the short answer is that since there's nothing inherently async about reading from a MemoryStream, there's no real work to send to another thread.

Comment: What you're looking for is a full tutorial on the `async`/`await` feature in C#. You should use your favorite web search engine to find one or more of the _many_ articles that describe what these keywords do. The previous comment sums up the specific behavior here though: the read from the in-memory object can complete synchronously, so you never wind up in a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `read from file` spawn a new thread but not `read from string`?

Let me clear here, neither of these calls are spawning a new thread -- and in fact, no new threads are created, or as my friend *Stephen Cleary* likes to say ["there is no thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

> Why does the asynchronous file IO require a new thread to complete?

Now, the reason that the thread identifier is different is due to the fact that one of these calls is actually leaving the file open. I created a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vE1xeR) that demonstrates that regardless of correctly waiting for the `async` calls to complete the thread id still changes. The clue is buried in the source code of the `StreamReader`. The `.ctor(string path)` ultimately passes in `true` on the `leaveOpen` parameter, whereas the `.ctor(Stream stream)` passes `false` for that parameter. Look at the two constructor paths [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,b5fe1efcec14de32).

*A quote from the aforementioned article:
Since the library/BCL is using the standard P/Invoke overlapped I/O system, it has already registered the handle with the I/O Completion Port (IOCP), which is part of the thread pool. So an I/O thread pool thread is borrowed briefly to execute the APC, which notifies the task that it’s complete.*

**Update**

I just ran it again and this was the results <kbd>[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ueBK15)</kbd>:

[image]

One thing that this seems to be telling me is that since the two that actually write to the file system, are truly I/O bound operations -- whereas the other one is simply in memory. Not sure if that helps to clarify things for you or not?

Comment: +1 I almost feel that stack overflow should require anyone posting a [c#] [async-await] question must read "there is no thread" before posting. The number of questions I've answered with that post boggles my mind.

Comment: The new thread is still created even if the `ctor` is changed to receive `FileStream` by `new StreamReader(File.Create("test.txt"))`.

Comment: I'm seeing the expected behavior, here's the [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ueBK15)...

Comment: @David Thanks. I ran your Fiddle so got  `59 59 142 142`. I'm expecting `59? 142! 142! 142!`. My test only with `ctor(FileStream)` got `59 142 142` but was expected `142 142 142`.

Comment: Stephen's article helps quite much clarify misconception on threading and AIO. IMHO, it badly needs code demos.